# PHP error_reporting is 0

Tags: php, apache

On my windows laptop I have Apache and PHP so I can develop websites locally. Then recently PHP files stopped reporting errors. In the php.ini file I have set

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & E_STRICT;

display_errors = On
```

But it still does not report any errors. If I echo error_reporting() i get 0.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: ok, it was already solved by the owner. but anyway, shouldnt this be moved to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that was stupid. I obviously meant `E_ALL | E_STRICT`, which fixed the problem.